# Need to modify the existing TASK SCHEDULING algorithms in Cloudsim. Which files should I use?

Tags: java, netbeans, cloud, cloudsim

I just started a small research work and in cloudsim and I need to modify the task scheduling algorithms which are already implemented there. I found various files on Power *cloudsim-3.0.3\examples\org\cloudbus\cloudsim\examples*. Most of them are on Load Balancing. pls help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduling algorithms in CloudSim are implemented by extending the [`CloudletScheduler`](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/CloudletScheduler.java) class. For instance, take a look a the [`CloudletSchedulerTimeShared`](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/CloudletSchedulerTimeShared.java) scheduler and how it is used in [CloudSimExample3](https://github.com/Cloudslab/cloudsim/blob/master/modules/cloudsim-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudbus/cloudsim/examples/CloudSimExample3.java). It is important that you understand the dynamics of this simple example before writing your first scheduler.

After that, follow these steps:

1. Write your scheduling algorithm as a class that extends `CloudletScheduler`.
2. Include your scheduler when creating virtual machines on your simulations:

`var vm = new Vm(vmid, brokerId, mips, pesNumber, ram, bw, size, vmm, new YourScheduler());`